# Laravel insert into mysql db from a controller function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to submit records into  a mysql table with many  fields by using a Laravel .blade.php view ( php form)

I made some trials but I get

**FatalErrorException in loginController.php line 54: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found**.

Mysql

```
create table users(id int primary key auto_increment,username varchar(20),password varchar(20),createDate timestamp );
```

My controller  function

```
    public function formSubmit()
{
    if (Input::post())
    {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');


       DB::table('users')->insert(array ('username' => $username,'password' => $password));
       return View::make('view2')->with(array('username' =>$username, 'password' => $password));
    }
     }
```

view1.blade.php form

```
 <form action="{{url('/view2') }}" method="POST"> 
 {{ csrf_field() }} 

   <input type ="hidden" name="">  
  User name:  <input type ="text" name="username">  <br/>
  Password     <input type="password" name="password">  <br/>

              <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="formSubmit"> 
 </form>
```

Route

```
    Route::get('/view1', 'loginController@formSubmit');
```

Comment: You can use `formSubmit(Request $request)` instead of `formSubmit()` and then `$request->username` will contain your username and `$request->password` will contain your password

Comment: `Route::get('/view1', 'loginController@formSubmit');` should be `Route::post('/view2', 'loginController@formSubmit');` for form submission and add another route for view1.blade.php containing method for `return view('view1');`

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Input;` to the top of your class right after `namespace` clause.

Or use full namespace:

```
$username = \Input::get('username');
$password = \Input::get('password');
```

Or you just could use [`only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-only) method to get an array from request:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(request()->only('username', password));
```

Also, never save raw passwords. Use [`bcrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-bcrypt) to encrypt passwords.

Comment: Unfortunately all the suggestions don't work with me

Comment: @CodingBoy I'm pretty sure these solutions will all fix the error you've shown. What exactly error do you get with each of those?

Comment: When using 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\input; error FatalErrorException in loginController.php line 11: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\input\Controller' not found getted

Comment: when using 
   DB::table('users')->insert(request()->only('username', password)); error FatalErrorException in loginController.php line 42: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Comment: And FatalErrorException in loginController.php line 11: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\input\Controller' not found  when using      $username = \Input::get('username');
$password = \Input::get('password');

Comment: You do not do what I've shown, that's why you're greeting these errors. Please reread the answer carefully again. For the last solution, remove or comment out other lines where you're using `Input`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Laravel 5, use the Request Facade and acces `input` this way:

`Request::input()`

instead of using Input();

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

And, just in case, include it at the top of the Controller with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to  Amarnasan answer  I used request and include use Illuminate\Http\Request; at the top of my controller.

So I changed my controller method to

```
  public function formSubmit(Request $req)
{

          $username =$req->input('username');
         $password =$req->input('password');

       DB::table('users')->insert(array ('username' => $username,'password' => $password));
       return view ('view2')->with(array('username' =>$username, 'password' => $password));

     }

}
```

and I changed my routes according to  Shubham pokhriyal commit to:

```
Route::post('/view2', 'loginController@formSubmit');
Route::get('view1',function()
{
return view('view1');   
}
);
```

and  it works fine.